# Return a large array from a function

Tags: php, function, memory-management, return, resultset

I have a class for an app that manages its database fetches. Instead of working with the result set ([PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)) in the class and echoing out the html from there, I'd like to return the result set back to the page using `fetchAll()`

```
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

*Edit:* I don't want to return `$stmt` because to my knowledge it is not good to have multiple existing `PDOStatement` objects existing from a single connection. To avoid the risk I'd like to manage these objects within the class. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Assuming the array won't be over 100k rows, maybe 10k-50k, are there any performance reasons (or any at all) why I should not be doing this? I know it's pretty basic, but what is the preferred way of handling this?

Will it make any difference of an impact on memory if I do this rather than working with it right in the class method? I would think it is okay, but I wanted to hear from SO.

Comment: It'll make a big memory impact working with a large array, why not return $stmt and do the fetches one row at a time

Comment: Define your function so it accepts a destination argument, like this: `function getData( $parm1, $parm2, &$dest_var )`; and then call it like this: `$my_data = NULL; getData( 'parm1', 'parm2', $my_data );` Within your fetch function, you're not returning a big array, but assigning it to a passed parameter, which _may_ be more memory efficient.

Comment: @MarkBaker Several page elements could potentially use this data class object, and I don't want to run the risk of having multiple PDOStatement objects outside of the class. Creating one will fail if there is already one who's cursor hasn't reached the end. So I'd like to keep them managed within the scope of the class method.

Comment: @J.D.Pace Clever idea :) I may try that if nothing else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If memory concerns exist then calling fetch all is not your friend, regardless of what you are doing... your better off just calling $stmt->fetch in an loop. Since php passes arrays by reference processing within the function vs deferring out to another should have about the same memory and performance profile.

Comment: You mean to return `$stmt` and loop from the calling scope? See my edit for why I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: More data is going to require more resources, I guess the big question is where do you have the room to stretch out. If the database overloaded to the point that having several concurrent statements open would be an issue then fetchAll will be the better option. If memory is the issue then returning the statement object and walking it in the calling scope would be better.